# How to handle guest user viewing a post?

Tags: php, session

I have a `post.php` page which shows posts on my site. It shows features/links according to the type of user visiting it, like for user who wrote the post (session holder) it will show edit and delete buttons while not for others. 
For this I am using sessions:

```
if(!empty($_GET['username'])) { 
$username = $_GET['username'];
}
else if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])) { 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else{
// do nothing
}
```

Now the problem arises for guest user (user not logged in) as for session holder `$_SESSION['username'];` is operative and for logged_in user (but not session holder) `$_GET['username'];` is operative, so guest user gets undefined variable on this page. To solve this I added `$username="";` to above `else` statement so now that statement is:

```
if(!empty($_GET['username'])) { 
$username = $_GET['username'];
}
else if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])) { 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else{
$username="";
}
```

This though solved my problem but I want to be sure if there is any security risk or other problem using this method. Any better idea's are welcome.

Comment: We can't tell you the security risks without knowing what is being exposed. That being said, `$_GET['username']` does not ensure a logged in user. Anyone can enter GET(or POST) variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first one use post method to get data

//after successfull login

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = generate token or true or false ur choice;

//restrict this in ur all contructor of view
if($_SESSION['loggedin']){
//ur accessible here you are authorized;
}
else {
//sorry we are redirecting you;

}
```